# Extracting tables from website

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the table from Morningstar into pandas

Website link - http://financials.morningstar.com/cash-flow/cf.html?t=3IINFOTECH&region=ind&culture=en-US

Since the website is Javascript, I am first rendering the website in my local browser using selenium and then reading the rendered HTML file from browser and trying to read the table.

The problem is the table is stored in a div style as below: this means that I cannot read the table using either pandas read HTML, or beautiful soup's read table functions. Both give the error `no tables found`.  Can somebody help me with an easy way to extract the data from the div nodes as I am new to Python. Below is a portion of the HTML script for the  table

```
"" style="overflow:hidden;white-space: nowrap;">
         25,875
        </div>
        <div class="pos column6Width109px" id="Y_2" rawvalue="16810200000" style="overflow:hidden;white-space: nowrap;">
         16,810
        </div>
        <div class="pos column6Width109px" id="Y_3" rawvalue="13113600000" style="overflow:hidden;white-space: nowrap;">
         13,114"
```

Comment: Can you at least post whatever you tried? Why not post your BeautifulSoup code? Show the error - that really helps us in helping you. Also post the entire div tag, so people can help you out. A single line won't help. Use 4 spaces before starting every line to format as code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data using just *requests* and *Beautifulsoup*, the html is retrieved with an ajax call:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from json import loads

import requests
from time import time

params = {'columnYear': '5',  'region': 'ind', 'rounding': '3', 'period': '12',
          'curYearPart': '1st5year', 'culture': 'en-US',  'reportType': 'cf', 't': 'XNSE:3IINFOTECH',
          'callback': 'jsonp{}'.format(str(int(time()))), 'order': 'asc', '_': str(int(time()))}
r = requests.get('http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4HtmlAjax.html', params=params)

cont = r.content

jsn = loads(cont[cont.find("{"):cont.rfind("}") + 1])
soup = BeautifulSoup(jsn["result"])

table = soup.select_one("div.r_xcmenu.rf_table")
headers = [d.text for d in table.select("div.rf_header [id^=Y_]")]
print headers
for row in table.find_all("div","rf_crow", style=False):
    print([d.text for d in row.select("[id^=Y_]")])
```

Which gives you:

```
[u'2011-03', u'2012-03', u'2013-03', u'2014-03', u'2015-03', u'TTM']
[u'3,511', u'(1,545)', u'495', u'498', u'(513)', u'(513)']
[u'975', u'1,092', u'2,308', u'2,564', u'2,291', u'2,291']
[u'\u2014', u'(80)', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'\u2014']
[u'(10)', u'6', u'5', u'2', u'(1)', u'(1)']
[u'(1,277)', u'(3,556)', u'(401)', u'(409)', u'(2,080)', u'(2,080)']
[u'3,823', u'995', u'(1,417)', u'(1,661)', u'(724)', u'(724)']
[u'(1,168)', u'4,953', u'(398)', u'(190)', u'3,137', u'3,137']
[u'(4,713)', u'(617)', u'(426)', u'(229)', u'\u2014', u'\u2014']
[u'232', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'89', u'89']
[u'\u2014', u'5,513', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'3,037', u'3,037']
[u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'(1)', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'\u2014']
[u'3,251', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'0', u'\u2014', u'\u2014']
[u'63', u'57', u'29', u'39', u'12', u'12']
[u'(2,207)', u'(3,843)', u'(604)', u'(168)', u'(3,026)', u'(3,026)']
[u'(1,482)', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'\u2014']
[u'1,816', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'\u2014']
[u'(151)', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'\u2014']
[u'(410)', u'(341)', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'\u2014', u'\u2014']
[u'(1,980)', u'(3,502)', u'(604)', u'(168)', u'(3,026)', u'(3,026)']
[u'136', u'(435)', u'(506)', u'140', u'(403)', u'(403)']
[u'1,806', u'1,318', u'884', u'377', u'518', u'518']
[u'1,941', u'884', u'377', u'518', u'115', u'115']
[u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'\xa0']
[u'3,511', u'(1,545)', u'495', u'498', u'(513)', u'(513)']
[u'(4,713)', u'(617)', u'(426)', u'(229)', u'\u2014', u'\u2014']
[u'(1,203)', u'(2,162)', u'69', u'269', u'(513)', u'(513)']
```

`u'\u2014'` is a unicode `_` which you see on the page for missing values.

Comment: Hi..Thank you so much for your response. But when I run the same script using Python 2.7, it gives me the the below error. It looks like you are able to run without any error. Is it because you are running Python 3. Also could you please let me know how to add the row header (index) to the above data?

Comment: Below is the error I get for the line : table = soup.select_one("div.r_xcmenu.rf_table")
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  File "C:\Users\abhis\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/abhis/Desktop/untitled0.py", line 24, in <module>
    table = soup.select_one("div.r_xcmenu.rf_table")

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Hi I was able to solve the above problem by commenting out the line which was giving error and replacing the variable "table" with the variable "soup" in the line below
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#table = soup.select_one("div.r_xcmenu.rf_table")

headers = [d.text for d in soup.select("div.rf_header [id^=Y_]")]

print headers

for row in soup.find_all("div","rf_crow", style=False):

    print([d.text for d in row.select("[id^=Y_]")])

Comment: Your post has helped me a lot to learn a lot of things. Please do let me know how can I import the labels of the row --Revenue, profit etc. Also am still curious to know why the original code worked for you but not for me..Thanks a lot for your help